# how to use plist item as self.title of next view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, plist

I have a plist which has an array of items that I display in a UItableView. I want to pass the plist item that is selected to the self.title of the next view, but am unsure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the [`title`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW33) is shorter route for a view controller.

```
nextViewController.title = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: yup, nice Simple cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in an array or dictionary, you can just assign it like any other string.

If this is from the `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, then you could do something like the following:

```
myNextView.navigationItem.title = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: its an array.
so i can just declare this say in my rootviewcontroller select method?.. I need to find that method...

Comment: right so I put this in my - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 

Cheers dude.